# Difference between Canvas and JPanel

Tags: java, graphics

1. What is the difference between the `Canvas` class and the `JPanel` class, as far as graphics goes?
2. Are there any advantages or disadvantages to either of these classes?
3. I always use the `Canvas` class. Should I be using one class over the other? If so, why?

Comment: to my knowledge if you are doing Swing development, all you have is the JPanel. there is no Canvas class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few differences. JPanel:

1. is a Container, so you can add other Components to it
2. setBackground will automatically fill the background color
3. Set / Add tooltip
4. Add a `Border`
5. printComponent for printing

Fairly minor stuff, but sometimes important

Answer (score 0):

Canvas: AWT
JPanel: Swing

Swing is based on AWT, so Canvas can be more lightweight and in lower layer.

If canvas meet all your requirements, just use Canvas.

PS: I don't think there would be too much expensive to use JPanel, just choose the one you like.